# Rotate 'something that can be drawn on Canvas'

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation, drawable

Hi have a problem regarding rotation. I'm currently drawing a few Objects on a Canvas. Currently this 'Objects' are just Bitmaps. After computing the rotation and passing it inside a Matrix, I'm forced to create a new Bitmap to get it rotated. A small snippet will clearify this:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    mMatrix = new Matrix();
    mMatrix.postRotate(getRotation());
    Bitmap rotateBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mMatrix, true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(rotateBmp, mCoords.x -(mBitmap.getWidth() / 2), mCoords.y - ( mBitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);
    rotateBmp.recycle();
}
```

All I can do to save memory is calling recycle on the `rotateBmp`, and it will run most of the time correctly. Lets assume I have 10 Bitmap 'Objects' I want to rotate. That means I have to keep ten Bitmaps as 'sample' and create ten new Bitmaps in every draw-cycle plus an additional new Matrix (didn't find a way to 'reset' it). This sounds very weird to me. Is there another Way, to create 'something that can be drawn on a Canvas' on the fly (no XML), while keeping control of their rotation. Any Idea is very welcome. If its a View, a Drawable or another CustomClass doesn't matter. Maybe it is important that `getRotation` will be all the same for every "Something" that should be drawn. What is the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the great help of @Jason Robinson and  [how To Rotate Text in Canvas](http://eleanordarephdjournal.blogspot.de/2011/03/another-good-android-example-with.html) I figured out a Way, of how I can do it. Here is a short snippet, that will work:

```
Bitmap mBitmap = getResources()...
int xPositionOfBitmap
int yPositionOfBitmap
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int bitmapCenterX = xPositionOfBitmap + (mBitmap.getWidth() / 2)
    int bitmapCenterY = yPositionOfBitmap + (mBitmap.getHeight() / 2)
    canvas.save()
    canvas.rotate(getRotation(),bitmapCenterX, bitmapCenterY)
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, xPositionOfBitmap, yPositionOfBitmap)
    canvas.restore()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate the `Canvas` using `canvas.rotate(float degrees)`

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mCoords.x -(mBitmap.getWidth() / 2), mCoords.y - ( mBitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);
    canvas.rotate(getRotation());
}
```

Comment: this will not keep the position of my Bitmaps.. They run 'out of the screen', if I'm changing the result of `getRotation`... lets assume: I draw my Bitmap at (0,0) and then rotating my Canvas by -90 deg: My Bitmap will get pushed out of the screen

Comment: That's because the anchor point for rotation is the top-left point (0,0). If you wanted a rotation anchored at the center of the image you'd have to post translate the canvas to emulate the center being the anchor point. Unfortunately, I'm terrible at geometry, so I'm unsure the algorithm you'd need to apply, but that is what you would need to do.